# Initialise Property Wrapper in the init

Tags: swift, property-wrapper

I have the following simple property wrapper

```
@propertyWrapper
struct TestWrapper<Value> {
    private var value: Value
    
    init(wrappedValue: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Value) {
        self.value = wrappedValue()
    }

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        mutating get {
            return value
        }
        set {
            value = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to define a property with it in a custom type and initialize it in the init and not in the declaration, like the following:

```
struct TestValueContainer {
    @TestWrapper var testValue: String
    
    init() {
        testValue = "Initial Value"
    }
}
```

This does not work and I'm getting a compile time error like

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

How can I make this work?

Comment: See the duplicate. You need to assign an instance of `TestWrapper` to `_testValue`.